# Using NTP to synchronise systems using different timezones

Tags: redhat, ntp

I have been trying to synchronize the time on 2 of my RHEL servers(Node1 and Node2) as I have to install a database which requires each node to be in sync. Both Node1 and Node2 are using the same server in /etc/ntp.conf i.e. Node3.

Node2 is perfectly synchronised with Node3 but Node1 is way off(5.5 hours). However, the 'ntpq -p' command doesn't show this difference.

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*Node3                 Node4     3 u   59   64  377    0.156    0.180   0.024
```

It shows an offset of just 0.18.

After spending some time trying to figure out the cause behind this, I've found that Node1 is on a different time zone(using the command: `date +"%Z %z"`)! Although the time really is in sync if you consider the time zone in which the nodes are operating but since I'm not sure how the DB will behave in such a scenario I want to bring Node1 on the same time zone as that of Node2.

Basically, I want to know what are the recommended steps to perform in order to get Node1 to use the same timezone as that of Node2/Node3.

**RHEL release**: 6.9

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I had to do was just create a softlink of a file pertaining to the time-zone to which I wanted to shift(delete the file if it already exists). As I wanted to change the time zone to IST(India Standard Time), I used the following command(from root user):

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime
```

And now, the date command on both of my nodes shows the same time.